# PHP - Check user role in array failing

Tags: php, arrays

I am grabbing my user role type, which is returned as an array, there is only ever 1 item - no problem though.

`$user_roles = $user_meta->roles;`

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'seller' (length=6)
```

There is always two potential values: `seller` and `vendor`.

I am checking for both, but always getting back false. I see nothing wrong with this in_array.

```
if ( in_array( array( 'seller', 'vendor' ), $user_roles ) ) {
    return true;
  }
```

I tested by putting die(); inside the conditional above which does not run, so for some reason it doesn't think 'seller' matches the array items.

Full code:

```
function is_vendor( $user_id ) {
  $user_meta = get_userdata( $user_id );
  $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

  if ( in_array( array( 'seller', 'vendor' ), $user_roles ) ) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `in_array` usage is wrong, it should be:

```
if (in_array($user_roles[0], array( 'seller', 'vendor' ))) {
    echo 'Is on array';

    return true;
}
```

`$user_roles` is an array as well with one element so you have to also pass the position.

See [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Ah, spot on, especially regarding the `[0]`. Thanks. - Will accept soon when possible.